# fgetc() doesn't work properly

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, eof, fgetc

I have file that goes like 7 4 5 1 etc. I want to put these number in a multi-dimensional array.

```
for(x=0;x<9;x++)
       for(y=0;y<9;y++)
       {
         current=fgetc(fp);
         if(current!=EOF&current!=' '&current!='\n')
              sudokuArray[x][y] = current-'0';
       }
```

This code doesn't work properly. sudokuArray[0][0] gives the result true(first number in the file) but [0][1] gives some random number like 131231304. [0][2] gives what [0][1] supposed to be. Why is that?

Comment: I think you should swap the "for x" and "for y" loops. BTW I am missing the definition of current. Also:  you want &&, not &. And you should add an else clause, setting the array to some special value, eg zero or -1.

Comment: How is `sudokuArray` defined ? And how is `current` defined ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because if your inner loop:

```
for(y=0;y<9;y++)
{
    current=fgetc(fp);
    if((current!=EOF) && (current!=' ') && (current!='\n'))
        sudokuArray[x][y] = current-'0';
}
```

If your input is `7 4 5 1`, then when `y == 0`, you read `'7'`, which gets put in `sudokuArray[0][0]`.

Now on your next loop, `y == 1`, and you read `' '`.  Because of your `if` statement, you don't put that in `sudokuArray` *but `y` still gets incremented*.

Next time you do the loop, `y == 2`, you read `'4'` and it gets put in `sudokuArray[0][2]`.

So `fgetc()` does work properly and your code is doing exactly what you told it to do.  Code is very obedient that way.

Edit: Also note your `if` statement should contain `&&` instead of `&`.  They are different operators.  A little whitespace and some parenthesis make the code easier to read and maintain as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you use nested loops to read from file. I see one problem in your code:

Change & to &&:

```
     if(current!=EOF&current!=' '&current!='\n')
```

to:

```
 if(current!=EOF && current!=' ' && current!='\n')
```

`&&` is the logical `AND` and `&` is bitwise AND.

Since, you have only integers and you seem to know the exact no. of integers. You can simply use `fscanf`:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d", &arr[x][y]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop you're ignoring characters - but then you're incrementing the indexes even though you haven't filled the related array element.  Try re-implementing as:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

for(x=0;x<9;x++)
    for(y=0;y<9;y++)
      {
      /* Get next character */

      current=fgetc(fp);

      /* Loop, retrieving additional chars, until either EOF is hit or 
         you find a non-whitespace character */

      while(current != EOF && iswhite(current))
        current = fgetc(fp);

      if(current != EOF)
        sudokuArray[x][y] = current - '0';
      }
```

Also - do you want to check `current != EOF`, or should this be `!feof(fp)`?

Share and enjoy.